# How to get all my google business account reviews using PHP (curl)

Tags: php, google-api

I need to get my google business account reviews . I have used  place API method

```
$parameters = "key=$api_key&placeid=$place_id";
$place_id = trim($place_id,' ');
$api_key = trim($api_key,' ');
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=$api_key&placeid=$place_id";  
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$res = json_decode($result,true);
return $res;
```

Its return only top  5 reviews . But I need to get all my business reviews . So that I go for below  link "https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v3/accounts/account_name/locations/location_name/reviews"  .

Here how shall I find  account_name and location_name , then what are parameter (like access token,and so on) to pass for execute curl. Please help to get all my business reviews .